# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_META'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to get the orientation of a video by using:

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
then calling
vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_META)
but I get the error in the title: " AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_META' "

I checked the cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKEND to make sure that I have a ffmpeg backend. cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKEND = 1900 matches cv::CAP_FFMPEG = 1900.

I should also mention that I'm inside an Conda environment with:

opencv                    3.4.2            py37h6fd60c2_1
opencv-contrib-python     4.4.0.42                 pypi_0

Was hoping to find if the video is "upside down" which my VLC media player can correct for, but when i read the frames with opencv they read upside down(180 degrees rotated). This lead me to believe that some rotation data may be stored in the metadata. Are there are other ways of easier getting the metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15499)

It is introduced in the newest opencv version.

I have opencv 4.5.1 installed and it's working just fine.